# How to specify selector for Polymer elements shadow dom elements?

Tags: puppeteer

I have a Polymer based web app that I'd like to test with Puppeteer.

What is the appropriate way to write the selectors for a case when there are several Polymer components embedded into each other?

The layout would be:

app > comp1 > comp2 > target_element

All the '>' marks a new shadow dom boundary.

What is the correct selector if I'd like to test the target_element at the end of the chain?

Comment: Is this app https://shop.polymer-project.org a good representation for your problem? If yes, can you point which target element reflects your problem. Oterwise give us different online polymer app.

Comment: Yes, that's perfect.
If I write
const shopApp = await page.$('shop-app');
const appHeader = await shopApp.$('app-header');

Then shopApp contains the element, but appHeader is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, it's not that [easy to select element in shadow dom](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/858). [Achim Weimert](https://twitter.com/AchimWeimert) show some workaround to [get pierce select through shadow dom](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/858#issuecomment-359763824). His method works for `app-header` in https://shop.polymer-project.org/:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const shadowSelectorFn = (el, selector) => el.shadowRoot.querySelector(selector);

const queryDeep = async (page, ...selectors) => {
    if (!selectors || selectors.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    const [ firstSelector, ...restSelectors ] = selectors;
    let parentElement = await page.$(firstSelector);
    for (const selector of restSelectors) {
        parentElement = await page.evaluateHandle(shadowSelectorFn, parentElement, selector);
    }

    return parentElement;
};


(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://shop.polymer-project.org/');


    const app = await page.$('shop-app');
    console.log(app);

    // you can not simply wait for element inside shadow dom
    // it's up to you how you detect if this element is ready
    await page.waitFor(2000);

    const header = await queryDeep(
        page,
        'shop-app', 'app-header'
    );
    console.log(header);

    await browser.close();
})();
```

It's worth mention that there is no easy way to detect when `app-header` element is ready. You can check this element in a loop with some time intervals or you should look for other solutions.

Comment: That's working perfectly for me. I'll play with the timing you mentioned. Thank you!

Comment: You can look here for example of a loop with timeout https://michaljanaszek.com/blog/test-website-performance-with-puppeteer#firstMeaningfulPaint (loop with `while (firstMeaningfulPaint === 0)`)

Comment: Great resource!